# How to print a word from list upon executing a bot command

Tags: python, discord.py

So I have this list of some `cars` below, and when I type in `!car`, the bot should be able to send only one word from the list but in an embedded message.
So every time I type in this command, the bot sends a single word, until it reaches the end of the list (ascending order).

**Example:**

List of cars: BMW, Mercedes, Porsche, Honda, Pontiac

**User:** !car

**Bot:** BMW

**User:** !car

**Bot:** Mercedes

Etc...

Here's my code: How can I modify it to fulfill my request?

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    cars = ['BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Porsche', 'Honda', 'Pontiac']

    if message.content == '!car'
        embed = discord.Embed(title=cars, description=None, color=0xfffb00)  
        # It prints the whole list, I would like only one word from the list.
        await message.channel.send(content=None, embed=embed)

client.run('token')
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you want to send them in ascending order you will need to save at which position of the list has been sent before so you know what to send next. Now the question is do you want to save this for the bot globally or user by user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an index-based approach. This will work for a list of any size > 0.

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

i = 0
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global i # omitting this breaks the code! be careful!

    cars = ['BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Porsche', 'Honda', 'Pontiac']

    if message.content == '!car'
        car = cars[i]
        i += 1
        i = 0 if i == len(cars) else i
        embed = discord.Embed(title=car, description=None, color=0xfffb00)  
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

client.run('token')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the length of the list, you can keep track of how many requests have been fulfilled and use that number to index into your list. As the list is static, I would move it outside your function, and use it like this:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
cars = ['BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Porsche', 'Honda', 'Pontiac']
num_cars = len(cars)
num_cars_requested = 0

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content == '!car'
        embed = discord.Embed(title=cars[num_cars_requested % num_cars], description=None, color=0xfffb00)
        num_cars_requested += 1
        # It prints the whole list, I would like only one word from the list.
        await message.channel.send(content=None, embed=embed)
```

So now your title is one element from the list, and it will rotate through the list by indexing using the number of requests, modulo the length of the list, which will be between 0 and the length of the list minus 1 -- perfect for indexing. And the `num_cars_requested += 1` will increment to obtain the next value on the next request.

Happy Coding (and happy Friday)!

Comment: Thanks for the reply
So I tried what you suggested.

When I put the variable outside the function, there seemed to be 
"unresolved references" for `num_cars_requested`

And when I put them inside the function it's working fine but it gives me the 1st word everytime.  How can we fix this?

Comment: You can use `global num_cars_requested`, and move it inside the function as well.

Comment: Thanks for the support!

Comment: Great, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge about how discord works, but if you want to randomly select an element from the list you can use random.choice()

```
import random
cars = ['BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Porsche', 'Honda', 'Pontiac']

print(random.choice(cars))
```

This will give you a random car name from the list each time.

Comment: I think @Zσυɱ is not just asking for a random word from the list but to go through the list one by one